# What's the difference between uglify-js and uglify-es?

Tags: uglifyjs

The descriptions of [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) and [uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) are the same except that uglify-es tacks "for ES6+" on the end. Based on that one would think uglify-es is the best option for ES6 code. On the other hand, uglify-es is older - version 3.3.9 published 5 months ago, versus uglify-js at version 3.4.2 published 2 days ago. Anyone want to clear up my confusion?

Comment: With uglify-js you need to transpile your ES6 code (babel) with uglify-es should be stright forward. Im not sure the versions between uglify-js and uglify-es being symetric but as far as I know. I have an old app (jquery) and I use uglify-es to minfy and uglify the code instead of new apps that uses webpack (which will take care of the js and the css)

Comment: According to the talk [Building a Platform: Webpack and the Future](https://youtu.be/nzb-dgNaImI?t=7m56s), uglify-es comes with (better?) parallelism and caching, resulting in a significant speedup for Webpack 4.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`uglify-js` only supports ES5 code as input.

`uglify-es` also supports ES6, but is buggy and has been abandoned.

[`terser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser) is a maintained replacement for it that can also handle ES6+.

Comment: where do you see that uglify-es has been abandoned? I'm asking because I use it for my projects. Just last week it got 1,3 million downloads, it really does not seem abandoned

Comment: by abandoned, Dan means it is no longer maintained. No developers work on the project, so it is out of date