# How to uglify ES6 javascript with Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, uglifyjs, flask-assets

I'm searching a `Flask-Assets` filter that allows me to uglify javascript and support ES6 syntax. I tried to use `uglifyjs-es` binary instead of `uglifyjs` but I can't figure out how to configure my filter to use the `uglifyjs-es` binary.

I've this:

```
my_app_js = Bundle(
    'js/MyApp.js',
    filters='uglifyjs',
    output='my_app_js.js'
)
```

From the [Webassets documentation](https://webassets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtin_filters.html#uglifyjs) :

> UglifyJS is an external tool written for NodeJS; this filter assumes
>   that the uglifyjs executable is in the path. Otherwise, you may define
>   a **UGLIFYJS_BIN** setting

Maybe the solution is there but I can't figure out where and how to change that `UGLIFYJS_BIN` setting, any idea ?

**Also**, I read [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/349) that `uglifyjs-es` project isn't maintenained anymore. terser seems to be the alternative, but could it be used as a filter too ?

### Edit

If you know a good alternative to `uglifyjs-es` with a code example, you win a bounty ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed uglifyjs using npm, it should be in the `node_modules` folder in your project.

You could configure flask as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UGLIFYJS_BIN'] = 'path/to/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs'
```

Regarding uglifyjs-es, you know it's unmaintained. But if your code gets minified using it, it's still a good option.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53194632/5476782):

- uglify-js only supports ES5 code as input.
- uglify-es also supports ES6, but is buggy and has been abandoned.

Comment: https://github.com/terser/terser seems also to be good option but I guess I need to create my own custom filter in this case

Answer (score 1):

Terser's command line is almost as baroque as with `ls`. I found that easiest for me is to use Rollup with Terser plugin, and there's ready made [Rollup filter for webassets](https://pypi.org/project/webassets-rollup/). This way all Terser configuration is done in Rollup's config that you specify in filter extra args. Minimal Terser's configuration for ES6 modules:

```js
{
  compress: {ecma: 2015, module: true},
  mangle: {module: true},
  output: {ecma: 2015},
  parse: {ecma: 2015},
  rename: {},
}
```

With configured Terser plugin you may now use it as if it was both bundle and minify filters applied:

```py
from flask_assets import Bundle
from webassets.filter import register_filter
from webassets_rollup import Rollup

register_filter(Rollup)

all_css = Bundle(
    'css/app.scss', filters='node-scss,cleancss', output='dist/all.%(version)s.min.css',
)

all_js = Bundle(
    'js/main.js', filters='rollup', output='dist/all.%(version)s.min.js',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set an environment variable named `UGLIFYJS_BIN`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash) for Linux instructions, or [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463212/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-windows) for Windows instructions.